# Amazon web services AmazonS3Client alloc giving error

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to learn how to use the `AWS S3 SDK` and thought uploading an image would be a good place to start(the tutorial is through Amazon). I used the exact code they supplied:

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = 
[[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY] autorelease];
```

But for some reason, `Xcode` doesn't have the `alloc` available for the `AmazonS3Client`. I've googled and searched through the forums and not found much so it's not a common problem. Anyone else having this issue and fixed it?

Comment: AmazonS3Client *s3 = 
[[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY] autorelease];   this is MRC

Comment: AmazonS3Client *s3 = 
[[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY];     //this is ARC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just write the code `autorelease` has deprecated in `iOS` 6

```
AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY];
```

you were imported

```
#import <AWSS3/AWSS3.h>
#import <AWSRuntime/AWSRuntime.h>
```

and call the .h file

```
@interface ArtistProfileViewController : UIViewController<AmazonServiceRequestDelegate>
```

[image]

Comment: Im still getting the error "No known class method for selector 'alloc'

Comment: @user3505651 see my screen shot It working fine for me , see my updated answer

Comment: which headers did you import?

Comment: I have all of those headrs imported and I called the .h file, but there is still not "alloc" option under "AmazonS3Client"

Comment: `AmazonS3Client *s3 = [[AmazonS3Client alloc] initWithAccessKey:MY_ACCESS_KEY_ID withSecretKey:MY_SECRET_KEY];`

Comment: Class method '+alloc' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Comment: its still not found AmazonS3Client for cocoapods.  i want to upload image to AWS server but i cant do that. please help me.